# unable to download file with django-filebrowser

Tags: django-filebrowser

Here is from settings.py. I can upload files, browse the file names.

```
# Main Media Settings
MEDIA_ROOT = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_ROOT", 'media')
MEDIA_URL = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_URL", settings.MEDIA_URL)

# Main FileBrowser Directory. This has to be a directory within MEDIA_ROOT.
# Leave empty in order to browse all files under MEDIA_ROOT.
# DO NOT USE A SLASH AT THE BEGINNING, DO NOT FORGET THE TRAILING SLASH AT THE END.
DIRECTORY = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY", 'uploads/')
```

On the browse page, I see the files are in this format:

URL  uploads/example.xlsx

Filesize  39.3 KB

But when I click on the URL link, I am directed to

8000/admin/filebrowser/detail/uploads/example.xlsx

with the complaints:

Using the URLconf defined in MIO_Risk.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^__debug__/
^admin/filebrowser/ ^browse/$ [name='fb_browse']
^admin/filebrowser/ ^createdir/ [name='fb_createdir']
^admin/filebrowser/ ^upload/ [name='fb_upload']
^admin/filebrowser/ ^delete_confirm/$ [name='fb_delete_confirm']
^admin/filebrowser/ ^delete/$ [name='fb_delete']
^admin/filebrowser/ ^detail/$ [name='fb_detail']
^admin/filebrowser/ ^version/$ [name='fb_version']
^admin/filebrowser/ ^upload_file/$ [name='fb_do_upload']
```

Any idea how this should work? or is it supposed to work at all? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per the author of django-filebrowser:

clicking the URL is handled by your server (resp. django), not the filebrowser. please check the django docs on how to server media files.

So following this link works like a charm:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/